# Database structure to house products with variable multiple options

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm looking for some ideas for a mySQL database to store products that have multiple (and variable) options and prices per product.   E.g. some products may require several columns to store details for each of the product options:

```
Product 1:
SKU
Name
General product description
--------------------------
options for product 1:
Height   Width   Depth   Weight   Material   Other_1   Other_2  Etc...   Price


Product 2:
SKU
Name
General product description
--------------------------
options for product 2:
Flow-rate   Material   Weight   Other_1   Other_2  Etc...   Price
```

I'm a little stumped because the number of columns and column names might be different for each product and each product may contain numerous options/prices.

So far I'm using a 'products' table and a 'prices' table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
product_id int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,product_type text
,product_page_1 text
,product_page_2 text
,product_page_3 text
,product_page_4 text
,product_sku text
,product_name text
,product_head text
,product_desc text
,product_image text
,product_sequence text
,product_flags text
,product_status text
,PRIMARY KEY (product_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=102;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
price_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,price_type text
,price_assoc text
,price_desc text
,price_option text
,price text
,price_sequence text
,price_flags text
,price_status text
,PRIMARY KEY (price_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=109;
```

There can be any number of 'prices' per product.  'prices' are associated with a product ID via 'price_assoc' field.

So I can have countless price entries for each product,  but whats the best way to add multiple price options per price being that each product may have varying options for its associated prices?

Comment: Surprised to see MyISAM - any particular reason?

Comment: The host I used inserted myISAM when I exported the DB to a text file.  Not sure why?!

Comment: It implies that they might be using a rather old version of MySQL

Comment: This is something of a FAQ, but that's not to say that there is a stock answer. I think it comes back to how many attributes are shared and how many are particular to just one (or a handful) of products. But as a rule-of-thumb, any time you see enumerated columns (other_1,other_2) that usually implies that you're doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, is a EAV table. Entity-attribute-value.
Thats the kind of structure where u have table of records, and then a table of subrecords.

Records table:

id
name
active

Subrecords table:

id
record_id
key
value

And then you can do a joined query where u get a record, and all the subrecords with it. So subrecords are in one to many relationship with records.

There is php example available in github: [here](https://github.com/dschreck/php-eav-example)

Comment: @Tidan If you are going to go down the EAV road, try to retain proper use of data types. So decimal values are stored in a DECIMAL data type and strings are stored in a VARCHAR data type. Also, note that EAV is notoriously difficult to work with!

Comment: Eav is considered a bad practice actually. Because that's not how you are supposed to use Relational database. But the answer i gave is just one of the options.

Comment: If this solved your issue, then please accept the answer. There are so many unaccepted but solved questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry,  still looking for more answers.  Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the same column for prices even though it is the same products. So instead of having to specify 4 columns for prices and descriptions for each row. Why not create a table with only on row for prices, one row for description/options/text etc. and then maybe ad a 'price-ID' field to keep track of different levels of prices.

Lets say you have one product, Product A, which have 4 different prices, then your prices table would look something like below:

```
product_id      product_name     price      description     option     text       price_ID
1               Product A        100        'Bla bla'         A          bla        1
1               Product A        250        'Bla bla'         B          bla        2
1               Product A        400        'Bla bla'         C          bla        3
1               Product A        500        'Bla bla'         D          bla        4
```

This way you can have as many prices for each product as you wish, and it takes down the complexity of your database a bit

Comment: This definitely feels like a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thats pretty much how it works.  I can have as many price rows per product as I want since each price is associated with a corresponding product.   But what I'll need is multiple price columns per price row.  Thanks regardless!

Comment: IF you would use EAV, you could have limitless number of custom columns associated with the product. That would be the point for using eav. It gives you dynamic dataset.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking - why do you need multiple price columns per price row? It seems to add unnecessary complexity to your database and hence to your query.

Comment: @Tidan They should still be rows, not columns - although they might be rows of some other table

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen Because each product will be different and some require several options such as 'material',  'width',  'height', 'depth', 'volume', etc....  and the prices will be different based on those options.  Other products will have 1 or 2 options only.  All need to be displayed in a table format on the front end.

Comment: @Tidan You can still achieve this using rows, by adding a control-column with e.g. numbers from 1-4 or however many set of prices per product you need. When you run your query for each product id you will then retrieve a list of prices, each with description etc., which you can then manipulate to have whatever format on the front end as you like.

Comment: So depending on how many products you have or types of products I would probably use two tables, one for prices and one for your products. If you have a lot of different types of products, each with different types of properties, I might take the EAV road. But if the biggest differences between your products is whether or not you should specify height, weight, colour or whatever, I would use just one table for your products.

Comment: @SteffenSylvestNielsen Should I include 10 extra columns in the 'prices' table to accomodate potential price options such as H, W, D, Weight, Color, Material,  etc... or would I use a seperate one-to-one table to house those columns?

Comment: @Tidan if the price is changing based on e.g. Weight, Color, Material etc. I would have a column in my design called "Type" or something like that, and then still keep all the prices in different rows. However if you mean that the product has a base price, and the price then changes based on selection of a variety of combinations of options such as height, weight etc. - I would probably add another table containing price-adjustments for each selection, or just keep it simple and still have them in one table.

Comment: To clarify. You have a row with the base price (100), then you have a set of rows with color_ids and how much extra the item will cost if you specify a particular color. Maybe color-id 1 is 10 extra, color-id 2 is 15 extra etc. Then you select all the relevant rows based on the specification the user selects on the front end.

Comment: Interesting.  I seperated prices from from products to avoid redundancy.  While there is a 'price' column in 'products', its not being used.  Prices are handled via the price table solely ATM. And each price may have various options such as H, W, D, etc... but it may have different options excluding H, W, D, etc...E.g. it may not have Height, Width, etc... it may instead have Volume, Material, Flow-rate, etc.

Comment: Ah okay I see what you mean. In that case and EAV design might be what you need. Assuming that everything can have different properties? Material will have different price if it is metal, plastic, silver, gold etc, and volume have different prices if it is 100, 200 or 300 or whatever your volume is measured in? Is that correct?

Comment: I think so, if I'm understanding you correctly.  So say productA has 35 different options including differing Height, Width, Depth, Material...Each one of those will be a different price within productA.  Whereas productB many have options like Flow-rate, Pressure, Material....And each one of those will have different prices within productB.   And all products will need to display on the front-end as a table with the price at the far right and an add to cart button.

Comment: Okay, then I would make a Product table, a basic product table and then multiple tables for each specific type of option. So if you have product A and an ID. You will fetch the base price from the price column, then you will fetch the relevant price from the Pressures table and the relevant price from the Material table, all joined based on the product ID. This way you have multiple tables, but managing everything may be easier than trying to price each combination of option manually before putting it in the db.

Comment: I'm scraping the 'base-price' idea and instead relying solely on the price table for pricing.  So productA price will be entered along with the corresponding options such as Height, Width, Material, etc... I simplified my example above to reflect this.  Hopefully it will make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve.  Apologies for any ambiguity!